# Auto update web pages of browser

Tags: html

I started learning html few days ago. one thing that frustrate me that I have to refresh the browser every time. I am using vs code. Is there another code editor that can automatically do this for me or some other browser. I am using chrome btw.

expecting : updates web pages automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to install another browser or code editor. You can just install [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extenstion in vs code; that automatically does the job for ya.

Comment: how do i install this in vs code?

Comment: there should be a extension tab on your left hand side of you screen. you can just search up live server in that and installtion should be pretty straight-forward from there